# Converting timestamp into readable format from JSON model

Tags: javascript, html, json, sapui5

I am making a comment section for certain pages on my site. I have a database set up to record the timestamp for every comment posted. But when i get the comments to display, i get the timestamp back (of course). How do i convert it into a readable format? The comments are stored in a JSONModel. Is there some way to do it inside the View.xml? or can i do it in the controller by formatting the JSON model?

Thanks for any help!

## JavaScript controller

```
onFindComments: function(oEvent)
    {
        var carriersitesModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("glParamCarrierSitesModel").getData();

        var sPath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("");
        var oComModel = new JSONModel(sPath);
        oComModel = RevisionDetailsService.onGetComments(carriersitesModel.periodNbr, carriersitesModel.carrierNbr, carriersitesModel.revisionNbr);

        this.setModel(oComModel, "commentModel");
        this.getView().byId("commentsList").setBusy(false);

    }
```

## Service

```
onGetComments: function(periodNbr, carrierNbr, revisionNbr) {

        var oModel = new JSONModel();
        oModel.setDefaultBindingMode("TwoWay");
        var sUrl = UrlProvider.getUrl("GET_COMMENTS");

        var param = {
            "url": window.location.href,
            "messageKey": periodNbr + "-" + carrierNbr + "-" + revisionNbr
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: sUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(param),
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
                oModel.setData(res);
                console.log("GET COMMENTS SUCCESS");
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
        return oModel;
    }
```

## View.xml

```
<semantic:content>
        <FeedInput
        id="FeedInput"
        post="onComment"
        class="sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom" />
        <Table id="commentsList" width="auto" items="{commentModel>/returnData}" noDataText="{i18n>commentLineItemTableNoDataText}"
            busyIndicatorDelay="{detailView>/delay}" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">
            <columns>
                <Column minScreenWidth="Phone" demandPopin="true" width="150px" style=" white-space:normal">
                    <Text text="{i18n>commentSenderColumnText}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column minScreenWidth="Phone" demandPopin="true" style="white-space:normal">
                    <Text text="{i18n>commentMessageColumnText}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column minScreenWidth="Phone" demandPopin="true" width="100px">
                    <Text text="{i18n>commentDateColumnText}"/>
                </Column>
            </columns>
            <items>
                <ColumnListItem>
                    <cells>
                        <Text text="{commentModel>createdBy}"/>
                        <Text text="{commentModel>message}"/>
                        <Text text="{commentModel>createdTime}"/>
                    </cells>
                </ColumnListItem>
            </items>
        </Table>
    </semantic:content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to format date (or any other type) in ui5:

1. [programmatically](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f2eba36f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html)
2. [declaratively](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/9252ee4015f24fc49c71c295394d1b8d.html)

In your case, it will look like this:

```
<Text text="{
    path: 'commentModel>createdTime',
    type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
    formatOptions: {style: 'medium'}
}"/>
```

For the different parameters usage, read the official documentation.

Comment: This is exaclty what i was looking for! Thank you! I am getting an error though. `Uncaught TypeError: j.getTime is not a function`   Am i missing something?

Comment: it order to check whether something is missing you need to add more info: how did you do the binding, how the data look like..

Comment: I just pasted your code over my `<Text text="{commentModel>createdTime}"/>`   I didn't change anything else

Comment: the date should come in the format "/Date(TIMESTAMP)/"

Answer (score 1):

A very useful javascript library for things like this is [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Just parse the timestamp into moment and use one of its many formatting methods.